AKS - Kubernetes Hierarchical Namespaces - no endpoints available for service hnc-webhook-service
I want to use Kubernetes Hierarchical Namespaces feature into an Azure Kubernetes Services cluster.
I tried to install it by following instructions from here
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/hierarchical-namespaces/releases/tag/v1.1.0
by applying this manifest
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/hierarchical-namespaces/releases/download/v1.1.0/default.yaml
I tried to test it after installing by running
kubectl hns
but the output was
error: unknown command "hns" for "kubectl"
I tried to inspect logs from deployment/hnc-controller-manager and there are a lot of errors like this:
{"level":"error","ts":1716470207.0235682,"logger":"controller.hierarchyconfiguration","msg":"Reconciler error","reconciler group":"hnc.x-k8s.io","reconciler kind":"HierarchyConfiguration","name":"hierarchy","namespace":"cb-bcde374b-3597-4464-9027-d58f0d670b05","error":"Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook \"namespaces.hnc.x-k8s.io\": failed to call webhook: Post \"https://hnc-webhook-service.hnc-system.svc:443/validate-v1-namespace?timeout=10s\": no endpoints available for service \"hnc-webhook-service\""}
I checked hnc-webhook-service service and seems to be fine:
Name:              hnc-webhook-service
Namespace:         hnc-system
Labels:            none
Annotations:       none
Selector:          control-plane=controller-manager
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.0.182.110
IPs:               10.0.182.110
Port:              unset  443/TCP
TargetPort:        9443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.63:9443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            none 

But what I noticed is that this endpoint
https://hnc-webhook-service.hnc-system.svc:443/validate-v1-namespace?timeout=10s
is not reachable from a cluster pod.
But can be reached instead by adding .cluster.local like this
https://hnc-webhook-service.hnc-system.svc.cluster.local:443/validate-v1-namespace?timeout=10s
I inspected the manifest file
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/hierarchical-namespaces/releases/download/v1.1.0/default.yaml
but I was not able to figure out how to update that piece of code to target the right endpoint.
Could you please guide me to solve this issue?

The issue you're facing seems to be related to the DNS resolution within your Kubernetes cluster. Specifically, it appears that the webhook service is not resolving correctly to the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) within the cluster. To set up Kubernetes Hierarchical Namespaces (HNC) in your Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS) cluster and solve the issue with the webhook service endpoint.
Install Hierarchical Namespaces (HNC) using the provided manifest on your AKS cluster
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/hierarchical-namespaces/releases/download/v1.1.0/default.yaml


Check the installation status of HNC components.
kubectl get pods -n hnc-system


To address the issue with the webhook endpoint, modify the service endpoint configuration:
Download the manifest:
curl -LO https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/hierarchical-namespaces/releases/download/v1.1.0/default.yaml


Open the default.yaml file and find the hnc-controller-manager deployment section. Modify the args section to include the DNS suffix .cluster.local.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hnc-controller-manager
  namespace: hnc-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      control-plane: controller-manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        control-plane: controller-manager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: manager
        args:
        - --webhook-cert-dir=/certs
        - --metrics-addr=:8080
        - --webhook-addr=:9443
        - --leader-elect
        - --cert-dir=/certs
        - --logtostderr
        - --v=2
        - --system-namespace=hnc-system
        - --webhook-endpoint=https://hnc-webhook-service.hnc-system.svc.cluster.local:443
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /certs
          name: cert
          readOnly: true

Apply kubectl apply -f default.yaml
After making these changes, ensure that the webhook service is reachable.
kubectl get services -n hnc-system

Now you can create a hierarchical namespace and verify its behavior.
kubectl create ns parent
kubectl create ns child
kubectl hns set child --parent parent
kubectl hns tree parent


Reference-

HNC quickstart
Hierarchical Namespaces
Example of Hierarchical Namespace
HNC How to Guide


Thanks for your clear instructions. I tried to follow them but I've got this error: flag provided but not defined: -webhook-endpoint. I double checked the "dashes" but still same error

Validate DNS Configuration Within the Cluster- kubectl run dnsutils --image=gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3 --command -- sleep 3600 then, exec into the pod to perform DNS lookups: kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup hnc-webhook-service.hnc-system.svc.cluster.local Check the details of the HNC webhook service kubectl describe service hnc-webhook-service -n hnc-system Ensure the service is targeting the correct pods and that the selector matches the labels on the HNC controller manager pods and update your thread with the outputs.

Since the -webhook-endpoint flag is not supported, revert any modifications that attempted to add unsupported flags to the deployment. Reapply the Original HNC Configuration kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/hierarchical-namespaces/releases/download/v1.1.0/default.yaml After reverting to the original configuration, watch the HNC deployment kubectl get pods -n hnc-system Logic behind it is adjustments to flags within the Kubernetes deployment must be supported by the underlying application binaries.
